# Using java to connect to Azure VM and obtain the running process

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to connect (login using user credentials or ssh key) to a azure linux node from logged in Azure VM.

Once login into the my Azure VM, i wanted to get login to the linux server (azure) using java and get execute the shell ps command.

i checked Azure Java api, but it provides a way to create VM.

Comment: There are couple of option that i tried, using ProcessBuilder/ Runtime.getExec() - using ssh hostname command.  VM was restricted for opening terminal, since message "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal..."

Another option i tried is using jsch. it worked, need to use ssh key for password less login.

Comment: If you want to execute the command in the Azure VM, you can use the vm extension to interact with the VM, see [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-virtual-machine-using-vm-extensions/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/samples/ManageVirtualMachineExtension.java). Maybe it's helpful.